# XSD - How to force a precise collection of attribute values

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a defined XML structure that cannot be changed. The real content of semantic definition and value is contained within the same XML element but with attributes:

```
    <FIELD Name="ID" value="non-empty">

    </FIELD>

    <FIELD Name="DATE" value "">

    </FIELD>
```

I would like to be able to describe in an XSD that these attributes **values** "ID" and "DATE" are inside my XML.

Is it possible?

Comment: The purpose would be to describe the precise ordered list of attributes value.

Answer (score 2):

You mean, you want to constrain the first FIELD to have Name="ID", the second to have Name="DATE", and so on?

You can't do that directly with XSD 1.0 (there's a rule that if two elements of the same name are siblings, they must have the same type, which means you can't apply different constraints to them).

Two possible solutions are (a) use a different validation technology, e.g. XSD 1.1 with assertions or Schematron, or (b) create a validation pipeline, in which step 1 transforms the structure to something like

```
<ID>non-empty</ID>
<DATE/>
```

and step 2 validates this transformed structure against a schema.

A side-benefit of this second approach is that the transformed XML is much easier to work with than your original.

Comment: This was exactly the intent. Thank you for these 2 options. I will try the 1st one as the XML structure is really frozen...